# Inline Template, Assign HTML as string to model Property

Tags: asp.net-mvc

is there a way in ASP.NET MVC(2) to do something like that:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <% Model.Pager.TemplateNextPage = { %>
            <li><a href={link-next-page}>Next</a></li>
        <% } %>
        <% Model.Pager.TemplatePageNumber = { %>
            <li><a href={link-page-number}>{number}</a></li>
        <% } %>
        <% Model.Pager.TemplatePageNumberActive = { %>
            <li>{number}</li>
        <% } %>
    </tr>
</table>
```

the general idea is to enable designers to specify templates.

Comment: Why can't the designers just change the HTML to whatever they like? <li>Next</li> or <p>Next</p> or...

Comment: The goal is a way to specify templates like that: 
PageNumber= <a href={pagenumber}>{number}</a>. 

I will modify the question to make it more clear.

Comment: I still have no idea what you are asking.  Do you want the ViewData or Model to trigger what is shown in the View, or do you just want different views?

Comment: `Pager` being which class or extension method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not like that no. The code betweeen "%>" and "<%" e.g.

```
<% Model.Pager.TemplateNextPage = { %>
  <li><a href={link-next-page}>Next</a></li>
<% } %>
```

... will translate to ...

```
Model.Pager.TemplateNextPage = {;
Response.Write("<li><a href={link-next-page}>Next</a></li>");
};
```

when compiled (ignoring the whitespace in the example).  So it does not really work.

What you can do however, is use Asp.Net WebForms controls and create a custom one. It will work within Asp.Net MVC page. Not all features work (e.g. related to form postback), but enough to do what you want.

E.g. a table control is like this:

```
<asp:Table runat="server">
    <asp:TableFooterRow>
        <asp:TableCell>foo</asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>faa</asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableFooterRow>
</asp:Table>
```

You could extend that - or create a control from scratch allowing you to create your own TemplateNextPage etc.

...but this is not Asp.Net MVC way - it is the old Asp.Net WebForms way. It just works within Asp.Net MVC pages.

The other option you have is to create your own template engine, but that's quite a lot of work and I assume the intellisense part is very important to you so it would screw that as well.